# Out put in console

Tags: eclipse, ide

```
package lesson1;

public class StarProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
          for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
          {
              System.out.println("*");
          }System.out.println();

     }
  }

}
```

For this program, I am getting out put

```
*
*
*

*
*
*

*
*
*
```

But I should get this right?:

```
* * *
* * *
* * *
```

What is the problem in my program?

Comment: Read the docs for `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

this may help  you. read [difference](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/CCCCCtopic/75550-difference-between-outprintln-and-outprint/) between `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`

change

```
for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
          {
              System.out.print("*");
          }System.out.println();
```

instead of

```
for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
          {
              System.out.println("*");
          }System.out.println();
```